# Solving a system of linear equations that has infinitely many variables (dynamic programming?)

Tags: systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

I have a system of equations of the following
$$z(n)=c+\delta\big[p_1z(n+1)+p_2z(n-1)+(1-p_1-p_2)z(n)\big]~~if~~n\geq 0$$
and
$$z(n)=\delta\big[p_1z(n+1)+p_2z(n-1)+(1-p_1-p_2)z(n)\big]~~if~~n< 0$$

One interpretation of the system is like... You receive a reward of $c$ today if and only if your state variable $n$ is non-negative. Tomorrow's reward is discounted with a factor $\delta$, which is $\delta\in(0,1)$.

And the state $n$ evolves as follows: it becomes $n+1$ with probability $p_1$, $n-1$ with probability $p_2$, and stays the same with probability $1-p_1-p_2$. $c$ is a fixed scalar.

How can I solve for $z(\cdot)$ in this case? It is a system of simple linear equations but with infinitely many variables.

If this is not solvable, would it be solvable if I add some boundary conditions and make it a finite problem? For example, restricting to $n\in\{-100,-99,\cdots,99,100\}$ and with some proper modification of the equations for $z(-100)$ and $z(100)$?

Comment: Potentially very interesting. Please consider providing background, context, motivation. Please break into sections. Please identify the mathematical questions and highlight them so that the reader can determine within seconds whether he or she is qualified to answer.

Comment: The Z transform may be helpful here.